# For $x\neq 1$ find $x$ such that ...

Tags: arithmetic

For $x\neq 1$, find $X$ such that:
$$x+1\mid 2$$
$$x+2\mid 3$$
$$x+3\mid 4$$
$$x+4\mid 5$$
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: $X=-179$ is one solution.

Comment: Can you conclude something about some divisors of $X-1$?

Comment: What about $X = 1 + 120k$ for $k=1,2,3...$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you! the divisors of $X-1$ are $3,4,5$ so $X=60*k+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that
$$x+1\mid 2$$
$$x+2\mid 3$$
$$x+3\mid 4$$
$$x+4\mid 5$$

We rewrite it in modular form.

$$x+1\equiv 0 (\mod 2)$$
$$x+2\equiv 0 (\mod 3)$$
$$x+3\equiv 0 (\mod 4)$$
$$x+4\equiv 0 (\mod 5)$$

Subtracting so only $x$ is on the left, you get, by rules of modular arithmetic,

$$x\equiv 1 (\mod 2)$$
$$x\equiv 1 (\mod 3)$$
$$x\equiv 1 (\mod 4)$$
$$x\equiv 1 (\mod 5)$$
Therefore, $x-1$ is divisible by $2, 3, 4, 5$. The least common multiple of $2, 3, 4, 5$ is $60$, and so one solution is $x-1=60$, and so $x=61$ is a solution.

A more general solution is all numbers one more than a multiple of 60, usually written as $x=60k+1$ for $k\in \mathbb {Z} $ (But $k \neq 0$ because $x \neq 1$).